# How to return nothing in Java

Tags: java, return, return-value, matcher

```
public String nameToPhone(String inputName) {
        /* (c) Allow the user to search a contact’s phone number using his/her name. */
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        // Store name as pattern
        p = Pattern.compile(inputName);
        // Match pattern with array name
        m = p.matcher(this.name);
        if (m.matches())
            return this.phoneNum;
        else
            return null;

    }
```

The function will be called with `System.out.print(phonebookArray[i].nameToPhone)`

Expected output:
display only phone number if searched name exist

Actual output:

1. `else return null` will display phone number and also "null" if name exist
2. `else return ""` will display phone number and a blank line if name exist

The issue is `return null` will display null and `return ""` will display a blank line. How can I return absolutely nothing?

Comment: You cant. The caller has to have the fallback logic, not this method. The caller has to do `if (result == null) dont do anything` or similar. By the way, you should prefer to use `Optional` as return type to indicate absence of a result, not `null` or `""`.

Comment: Hi& Welcome! Maybe you *want* a `void` method, that (occasionally) prints... (The `if` statement is in place) When you have to stick with this "signature", then your (only!?) choice is to print (only) `if (result != null)`..

Comment: maybe a null check with the function call? `String output = pba[i].nameToPhone("name"); if (output != null) { System.out.print(output); }`

Comment: @Zabuzard thanks! it works and now only i know the Optional value

Comment: @xerx593 i have tried that and it also works! however, i think applying `result != null` logic in the main program leaves less stacktrace (maybee) but thank you very much

Comment: If you return `Optional`, the call site could look like `pba[i].nameToPhone("name").ifPresent(System.out::println);`, which is fairly compact and readable. Generally, you should prefer that over `null` and `""` for multiple reasons.

Comment: You can return java.lang.Void "type" in java. Much alike void (no type) as a method type. The clause is for the java.lang.Void method type use the return statement with null. So, public java.lang.Void noValueBack(){ // Some code here;  return null; }

Answer (score 1):

> You cant. The caller has to have the fallback logic, not this method. The caller has to do `if (result == null)` dont do anything or similar. By the way, you should prefer to use `Optional` as return type to indicate absence of a result, not `null` or `""`. – [Zabuzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411243/zabuzard)